# Problem with disappearing arguments in R - .Primitive("call") unevaluated promise

Tags: r, arguments

I have the following function:

```
fitWindowing <- function(sfa, samples, windowSize, wordLength, symbolSet, normMean, lowerBounding) {
  sfa[["transformation"]] <- createMFT(windowSize, normMean, lowerBounding)
  # some code
  catch <- fitTransformSupervised(sfa, sa, wordLength, symbolSet, normMean)
  # some code
  return(sfa)}
```

When I call it:

```
weasel[["signature"]][[index]] <- fitWindowing(weasel[["signature"]][[index]], samples, weasel[["windowLengths"]][index], weasel[["maxF"]], weasel[["symbolSet"]], weasel[["normMean"]], FALSE)
```

it passes all arguments but `weasel[["maxF"]], weasel[["symbolSet"]]` (numbers). During debugging the function keeps `.Primitive("call") (unevaluated promise)` in their place and passes 0's to `fitTransformSupervised` instead of correct values. `weasel` stores correct values and reassigning them doesn't solve the issue. Interestingly, these two arguments are the only ones not used in `fitWindowing` before passing them to `fitTransformSupervised`, yet `createMFT` handles all arguments correctly. How can I force `fitWindowing` to also get/use all arguments properly?

**Edit: code**

`weasel`:

```
createWEASEL <- function(maxF, maxS, windowLength, normMean) {
  weasel <- list()
  weasel[["maxF"]] <- maxF
  weasel[["symbolSet"]] <- maxS
  weasel[["windowLengths"]] <- windowLength
  weasel[["normMean"]] <- normMean
  weasel[["signature"]] <- vector("list", length(weasel[["windowLengths"]]))
  weasel[["dict"]] <- createDictionary()
  return(weasel)
}
```

function calling `fitWindowing`:

```
createWords <- function(weasel, samples, index, bar) {
  if (is.null(weasel[["signature"]][[index]])) {
    weasel[["signature"]][[index]] <- createSFA("INFORMATION_GAIN", TRUE, FALSE)
    weasel[["signature"]][[index]] <- fitWindowing(weasel[["signature"]][[index]], samples, weasel[["windowLengths"]][index], weasel[["maxF"]], weasel[["symbolSet"]], weasel[["normMean"]], FALSE)
  }
  wordsList <- list()
  catch <- list()
  for (i in 1:samples[["samples"]]) {
    catch <- SFAWindowingInt(weasel[["signature"]][[index]], samples[["tseries"]][[i]], weasel[["maxF"]])
    weasel[["signature"]][[index]] <- catch[[1]]
    wordsList[[i]] <- catch[[2]]
  }
  weasel[["words"]][[index]] <- wordsList
  if (!is.null(bar)) {
    setTxtProgressBar(bar, index)
  }
  return(weasel)
}
```

and `fitWindowing`:

```
fitWindowing <- function(sfa, samples, windowSize, wordLength, symbolSet, normMean, lowerBounding) {
  sfa[["transformation"]] <- createMFT(windowSize, normMean, lowerBounding)
  sa <- list()
  index = 0
  
  for (i in 1:samples[["samples"]]) {
    newList <- getDisjointSequences(samples[["tseries"]][[i]], windowSize, normMean)
    for (j in 1:length(newList)) {
      index = index + 1
      sa[[index]] <- newList[[j]]
    }
  }
  sa[["samples"]] <- index
  catch <- list()
  if (sfa[["SUP"]] == TRUE) catch <- fitTransformSupervised(sfa, sa, wordLength, symbolSet, normMean)
  else catch <- fitTransform(sfa, sa, wordLength, symbolSet, normMean)
  return(catch[[1]])
}
```

**Edit No. 2: more code**

Creation of `weasel`:

```
fitWEASEL <- function(classifier, train) {
  maxCorrect = -1
  bestF = -1
  bestNorm = FALSE
  classifier[["minWindowLength"]] <- 4
  maxWindowLength = classifier[["maxWindowLength"]]
  for (i in 1:train[["samples"]]) {
    maxWindowLength = min(length(train[["tseries"]][[i]][["data"]]), maxWindowLength)
  }
  classifier[["windows"]] <- classifier[["minWindowLength"]]:maxWindowLength
  
  keepGoing = TRUE
  catch <- list()
  for (normMean in c(TRUE, FALSE)) {
    if (keepGoing) {
      weasel <- createWEASEL(classifier[["maxF"]], classifier[["maxS"]], classifier[["windows"]], normMean)
  # more code
}
```

function calling the function calling `fitWindowing`:

```
createFitting <- function(weasel, samples) {
  weasel[["words"]] <- rep(NA, length(weasel[["windowLengths"]]))
  print("Fitting...")
  for (i in 1:length(weasel[["windowLengths"]])) {
    weasel <- createWords(weasel, samples, i, NULL)
  }
  value <- list()
  value[[1]] <- weasel
  value[[2]] <- weasel[["words"]]
  return (value)
}
```

[weasel args as visible from createWords](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4WUK.jpg)

[args passed to fitWindowing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5JoN.jpg)

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: You might find `?force` useful here - can't say for sure without a reproducible example.

Comment: Can you show us the call to `createWEASEL` that you have used to construct `weasel`, and show us the call to `createWords` that produces the issue you have described, _and_ tell us what packages you have loaded (e.g., by pasting the output of `sessionInfo()`)?

Comment: @MikaelJagan I hope this is enough, I don't think that posting all the route is possible (2000 lines of nested functions), moreover copying values, converting them by `as.integer()` doesn't help. I used no additional packages throughout the whole project. `force` helped partially - values were passed to the next function correctly but then the same issue appeared after passing them again to the following functions